# why data from firebase is not displayed?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

First, 'main.dart' calls 'homepage.dart'.
And 'homepage.dart' calls several pages in the body(the code'_pages[_index]') using bottomnavigationbar and index.
Initially, index is 0 and 'Ppage1' appears by default.
In this 'Ppage1', I brought the collection 'exhibition' from firestore.
And then called the '_buildBody'(if data is not arrived,LinearProgressIndicator will be displayed) ,
and in there i made the list 'exhibitions' using 'Exhibition'. (Previously, I had made a data model called 'Exhibition' in 'model_exhibitions.dart'.)
And in the '_buildBody', I brought the class 'BoxSlider' that is using the data from firebase.
I think the data is arrived wel since the LinearProgressIndicator is not displayed.
But only the UI using the data from firestore is not displayed.
What is problem? i can't find it

homepage.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var _index = 0;
  final _pages = [
    Ppage1(),
    const Page2(),
    const Page3(),
    const Page4(),
    const Page5(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar( ...
```

Ppage1.dart

```
class Ppage1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Ppage1> createState() => _Ppage1State();
}

class _Ppage1State extends State<Ppage1> {
  FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    streamData = firebaseFirestore.collection('exhibition').snapshots();
  }

  Widget _fetchData(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('exhibition').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
        return _buildBody(context, snapshot.data!.docs);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    List<Exhibition> exhibitions = snapshot.map((d) => Exhibition.fromSnapshot(d)).toList();
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
BoxSlider(exhibitions: exhibitions), ...
```

box_slider.dart

```
class BoxSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  late final List<Exhibition> exhibitions;
  BoxSlider({required this.exhibitions});

  @override
  State<BoxSlider> createState() => _BoxSliderState();
}

class _BoxSliderState extends State<BoxSlider> {

  late List<Exhibition> exhibitions;
  late List<Widget> posters;
...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    exhibitions = widget.exhibitions;
    posters = exhibitions.map((m) => Image.asset(m.poster)).toList();
 ...
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 440,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: makeBoxImages(context, widget.exhibitions),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Widget> makeBoxImages(BuildContext context, List<Exhibition> exhibitions) {
  List<Widget> results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < exhibitions.length; i++) {
    results.add(
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>DetailScreen(exhibition: exhibitions[i])),
            );
            },
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 350,
              child: Image.network(exhibitions[i].poster),
            ), ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the `_fetchdata` method to know if the data is fetched correctly:

```
Widget _fetchData(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('exhibition').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        //To know if the snapshot contains errors.
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('Some error occured: ${snapshot.error.toString()}'),
          );
        }

        //To know if the snapshot contains valid data.
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return _buildBody(context, snapshot.data!.docs);
        }

        //Returns a progress indicator in case that the two conditions above are not satisfied.
        return LinearProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I corrected like that, and still same. That means the data from firestore is well arrived... Do you know what can i do?